# Группировка таблицы по выборочному диапазону дат для каждой группы

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, group-by

Имеется таблица продаж по магазинам:

```
        Дата     Магазин  Продажи
0   01.01.2020   first        1
1   02.01.2020   first        2
2   03.01.2020   first        3
3   04.01.2020   first        5
4   05.01.2020   first        0
5   01.01.2020  second        2
6   02.01.2020  second       33
7   03.01.2020  second       44
8   04.01.2020  second       11
9   05.01.2020  second       22
10  06.02.2021   third      100
11  07.02.2021   third      200
12  08.02.2021   third      300
13  09.02.2021   third      400
14  10.02.2021   third      500
15  11.02.2021   third      900
```

Также имеется таблица периодов проведения скидочных акций в этих магазинах:

```
  Магазин Начало периода Конец периода
0   first     01.01.2020    02.01.2020
1   first     04.01.2020    05.01.2020
2  second     03.01.2020    04.01.2020
3   third     06.02.2021    08.02.2021
4   third     10.02.2021    11.02.2021
```

Необходимо найти сумму за периоды проведения акций для каждого магазина.

Результат:

```
  Магазин  Счётчик  Продажи
0   first        1        3
1   first        2        5
2  second        1       55
3   third        1      600
4   third        2     1400
```

Решил эту задачу с помощью двух циклов:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({
      'Дата':    ['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020','06.02.2021','07.02.2021','08.02.2021','09.02.2021','10.02.2021','11.02.2021'],
      'Магазин': ['first','first','first','first','first','second','second','second','second','second','third','third','third','third','third','third'],
      'Продажи':   [1,2,3,5,0,2,33,44,11,22,100,200,300,400,500,900] })
    
    df['Дата'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Дата'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
    
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'Магазин': ['first','first','second','third','third'],
                         'Начало периода': ['01.01.2020','04.01.2020','03.01.2020','06.02.2021','10.02.2021'],
                         'Конец периода' : ['02.01.2020','05.01.2020','04.01.2020','08.02.2021','11.02.2021']})
    
    df2['Конец периода'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Конец периода'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
    
    df2['Начало периода'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Начало периода'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
    
    uniq_shop=df2['Магазин'].unique()
    
    df['Счётчик']=0
    
    for name in uniq_shop:
        
        df_date_start=df2['Начало периода'].loc[df2['Магазин']==name].reset_index(drop=True)
        df_date_end=df2['Конец периода'].loc[df2['Магазин']==name].reset_index(drop=True)
         
        for i in range(len(df_date_start)):
            df.loc[(df['Дата']>=df_date_start[i])&(df['Дата']<=df_date_end[i])&(df['Магазин']==name),['Счётчик']]=i+1
    
    df=df.loc[df['Счётчик']!=0]
    results=df.groupby(['Магазин', 'Счётчик']).sum().reset_index()
```

Можно ли обойтись без циклов и сразу сгруппировать данные или как-то более эффективно получить столбец 'Счётчик'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать вспомогательный фрейм `x` из фрейма `df2`:

```
x = pd.concat(df2
              .assign(Счётчик=df2.groupby("Магазин").cumcount().add(1))
              .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({"Дата": pd.date_range(x["Начало периода"], x["Конец периода"])})
                                 .assign(Магазин=x["Магазин"], Счётчик=x["Счётчик"]), 
                     axis=1)
              .to_numpy())
```

который будет выглядеть так:

```
In [135]: x
Out[135]:
        Дата Магазин  Счётчик
0 2020-01-01   first        1
1 2020-01-02   first        1
0 2020-01-04   first        2
1 2020-01-05   first        2
0 2020-01-03  second        1
1 2020-01-04  second        1
0 2021-02-06   third        1
1 2021-02-07   third        1
2 2021-02-08   third        1
0 2021-02-10   third        2
1 2021-02-11   third        2
```

после этого можно воспользоваться обычным `DataFrame.merge()`:

```
res = df
      .merge(x, on=["Магазин", "Дата"])
      .groupby(["Магазин","Счётчик"])
      ["Продажи"]
      .sum()
      .reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [137]: res
Out[137]:
  Магазин  Счётчик  Продажи
0   first        1        3
1   first        2        5
2  second        1       55
3   third        1      600
4   third        2     1400
```